# Password manager solution: Symbian based phone and a Linux machine (Windows is not important, but would be nice)

Tags: linux, passwords, mobile-phone, password-management, symbian

I currently use KeePassX to manage my passwords on my Linux (Xubuntu) machine. It's nice to have all the passwords encrypted, but sometimes I'd like to be able to tell a password when I'm on the run.

Therefore I'm looking for a solution which I can synchronize with my phone. I have a Nokia N82 which is a Symbian OS v9.2 based phone for the S60 3rd Edition platform with Feature Pack 1.

I like an open source solution if it's possible. In case it isn't I wouldn't mind paying for a good solution. If Windows may be added to the synchronization mix it's nice, but it's absolutely not a primary requirement (I don't even have any computer running Windows).

Answer (score 1):

Well there are many ports of Keepass, I'm not overly familiar with Symbian, does it support J2ME applications? If so there's two versions of Keepass (for J2ME), so all you'll need to do is synchronise your database.kdb file:

- [Keepass J2ME](http://keepassj2me.sourceforge.net/)
- [Keepass Mobile](http://www.keepassmobile.com/)

Keepass did start out as a Windows application, and is available for a number of other platforms. For links to all the various ports of Keepass see the [Keepass Homepage](http://keepass.info/download.html)

Comment: Thank you for answering. It supports J2ME applications. But neither one of those two solutions seems to be a complete working solution. I need a way to synchronize the database with the phone. And I need to be able to create new passwords on the phone and sync them to my computer.

So I guess I'm looking for something non-Keepass.

Comment: Admittedly a different scenario, but I've set up Keepass for someone between a Windows Mobile phone (running KeepassPPC) and a Vista PC (running the standard Keepass client). All that was necessary was to add the database.kdb file to the sync'ed files for the mobile to keep it synchronised between both. Can you do something similar with your Symbian phone? As I said I'm not au fait with Symbian.

Answer (score 1):

The application SymSync (http://www.telexy.com/Products/ProductInfo.aspx) to sync the data and your preferred password management application of choice may do the trick.